# Mongoose updating a document by ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an issue where if I try to update a document by ObjectId, I get a MongooseError.CastError. Any help?

```
var comment = new Comment({
    contents: 'contents'
})

console.log(typeof req.body.postId) // 'string'

Post.update({_id: db.Types.ObjectId(req.body.postId)}, { // 'cast error'
    commentsId: {$push: comment._id}
}, function(err, numAffected, res){
    if (err) { return next(err)}
    console.log('success')
})
```

Comment: You can also use `findByIdAndUpdate` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let Mongoose do the casting for you based on the defined schema.

```js
Post.update({_id: req.body.postId}, {commentsId: {$push: comment._id}}, ...
```